# How can I keep the value after I submit the value with jquery and ajax in this situation?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Click http://jsfiddle.net/4y1b1j8g/13/ to see the result. When I input a value in the input and press Enter, the value will replace dog value. But that is not what I want. I want to keep the value. for example, enter cat, it will become dog cat, enter mouse, it will like dog cat mouse. How can I do that?Appreciate.

```js
$( "#input" ).keydown(function( event ) {

if ( event.which == 13 ) {
   event.preventDefault();
    
    //put input value into div
var value=$('#input').val();
    $('#test').text(value);
   
   
     
}
    
    
});
```

```html
<div class="test" id="test">dog</div>
<input type="text" id="input"/>
```

Comment: then just get the current value and concatenate and reassign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is concatenate the string, not replace it. You'll need to get the previous value (`.html()`) and add the new value to it.

You could do that simply, by changing your `.text()` line to this:

```
$('#test').text($('#test').html() + " " + value);
```

As you can see, we grab the previous value from the div via the `.html()` event and then append the value.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/4y1b1j8g/14/)

---

You could alternatively use the `.append()` method which will concatenate the string for you:

```
$('#test').append(" " + value);
```

And here is an example for this method: [**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4y1b1j8g/15/)

---

#### Notes

The `" " + value` is adding a white space before you append the string, you can simple remove it if you don't want that, I just assumed you wanted readable text.

Answer (score 2):

use `append`. Try this:

```
 $("#input").keydown(function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            event.preventDefault();

            //put input value into div
            var value = $('#input').val();
            $('#test').append(value);
        }
    });
```